# How to let code in function to "know" that they are run in context of response in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I call some cloud that allows to execute groovy scripts.
I return data as xml from this scripts.
I use code like this:

```
def writer;
def xml;
writer = new StringWriter();
xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer);

xml.Response() {
   node('arrtibute1': value4arrtibute1);
}
```

But I need to use more sophisticated way to calculating values. I want to put a lot of different nodes in this.

```
def writer;
def xml;
writer = new StringWriter();
xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer);

xml.Response() {
   Function1();
   Function2();
}
```

...
and implementations of this functions.

```
public void Function1(){
   node1('arrtibute1': value4arrtibute1);
}
public void Function2(){
   someOtherNode1('arrtibute1': otherValue4arrtibute1, ...);
}
```

Latest code doesn't work. The reason why it doesn't work is functions don't know that they run in context of response and looking for methods `node1` and `someOtherNode1`.

When I try to pass xml in functions and try to create new response there I have deformed structure of xml document (document in document).

My question: how to let code in function to "know" that they are run in context of response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the builder into the functions you are calling like so:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

value4arrtibute1 = 'val1'
otherValue4arrtibute1 = 'val2'

public void function1( MarkupBuilder builder ){
   builder.node1('arrtibute1': value4arrtibute1 )
}

public void function2( MarkupBuilder builder ){
   builder.someOtherNode1('arrtibute1': otherValue4arrtibute1 )
}

String output = new StringWriter().with { writer ->
  new MarkupBuilder(writer).with { xml ->
    xml.Response() {
      function1( xml )
      function2( xml )
    }
  }
  writer
}

println output
```

Answer (score 1):

@tim_yates is correct in his answer, although I'd like to share another method of accomplishing the same sort of thing without having to pass the builder or delegate around.

In practice I usaually would make both function1 and function2 Closures and set their delegates to the builder.

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

value4arrtibute1 = 'val1'
otherValue4arrtibute1 = 'val2'

Closure function1 = {
   node1('arrtibute1': value4arrtibute1 )
}

Closure function2 = {
   someOtherNode1('arrtibute1': otherValue4arrtibute1 )
}

String output = new StringWriter().with { writer ->
  new MarkupBuilder(writer).with { xml ->
    xml.Response() {
      firstNode()
      xml.with function1
      xml.with function2
    }
  }
  writer
}

println output
```

Comment: Thanks that presents this grace solution.